# SimpleXML Parse Errors due to line breaks

Tags: php, xml, parsing, rss

This is a part of the xml that is causing the issue.

```
<jobUrlParameter>?jobid=59077373</jobUrlParameter><jobClientRef
erence>
```

This happens to random elements through out the xml which causes the following parse error when I try to load the file using simplexml_load_file.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): parser error : expected '>'
```

I'm a newbie so is there any way I could get the line breaks between elements removed?

Comment: I can't promise this will work, but try removing all the linebreaks and see what happens. Load the file into a string, run the string through `str_replace()` and use `simplexml_load_string()`

Comment: Sorry it took me forever to reply but yeah, I got it working temporarily using `str_replace()` which does have it's disadvantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the file into a string, run the string through `str_replace()` and use `simplexml_load_string()`

Something like

```
$xml=file_get_contents('path/to/file.xml');
$xml=str_replace("\n",'',$xml);
$simple=simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did after I read your comment :) - Thanks